# sqlalchemy left join on multiple tables with group by

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have this group by query:

```
        dis_data = db.session.query(Dis, DisUser, DTypes, DisUser.did,
        func.count(DisUser.did).label('dis_count')).\
        filter(Dis.id == DisUser.did, Dis.tid==DTypes.id).\
        group_by(DisUser.did).all()
```

However it only returns items from `Dis` which a user selected. DisUser  holds this many-to-many relation between Dis and User. But I want to have all items in Dis.
How can I change it to a left outer join?

I tried this which gives error:

```
    _data = db.session.query(Dis, DTypes, DisUser.did, 
    func.count(DisUser.did).label('dis_count')).\
    select_from(Dis, DTypes).outerjoin(DisUser).\
    filter(Dis.id == DisUser.did, Dis.tid==DTypes.id, 
           DTypes.id == dtype).group_by(DisUser.did).all()
```

The error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Don't know how to join to <Mapper at 0x7f88d80cd520; DisUser>. Please use the .select_from()
> method to establish an explicit left side, as well as providing an
> explicit ON clause if not present already to help resolve the
> ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the query with this, the point is that in groupby I should use a column from left table:

```
_data = db.session.query(Dis,DTypes,
         func.count(DisUser.did).label('dis_count'))\
  .outerjoin(DisUser, Dis.id==DisUser.did)\
  .filter(DTypes.id == Dis.tid, DTypes.id == dtype)\
  .group_by(Dis.id)
```